# Docker run not recognizing --rm

Tags: docker, docker-run

I am trying to set up a docker container that automatically deletes itself when done. I see there is a command to do this built into docker with the --rm flag.

I have my image and can build a container and run a job from an azure agent in it. The only thing left to do is to have it clean up after itself.

Here is the command I use to run it:

```
docker run -e SOMESTUFF dockeragent:latest --once --rm
```

And this is the error I get:

```
docker : Unrecognized command-line input arguments: 'rm'. For usage refer to: .\config.cmd --help or ./config.sh --help
At line:1 char:1
```

Why can it not recognize the input rm?
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up---rm

Comment: Did my solution help you?

Comment: Yes that was the solution thank you

Comment: In that case, accept my answer (green tick) and upvote it

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for the command is

```
$ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

So it should be

```
docker run ... --rm ... dockeragent:latest SOMESTUFF
```

Answer (score 2):

All flags should come before the container name:

```
$ docker run --rm -e SOMESTUFF dockeragent:latest ...
```

everything that comes after the image name is passed as an argument to the entrypoint